# Selenium Webdriver chromedriver click() behaves different with latest chrome 116+

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I had code that was working before 116.0.5845.96 (I am not sure if this part is relevant yet)

--- Edit:
I did some more testing around the code. It is not the issue with that click but the page itself is not loading correctly.

I just go to the page directly - and the DOM does not look like it fully loaded. One of dropdowns has no data. Some clicks(?) don't work. I would need to execute Click() twice for it to actually open up my modal.

I am at a loss as to what changed, my script itself did not change. The only possible changes have been in chromedriver, maybe something on my app, but I am not aware of any major changes happening.

Any even far-fetched suggestions would be helpful. I am grasping at straws right now.

Comment: using ".valid.selector" (that seems like a style applied upon validating something...) might be causing a timing issue there... or it's clicking a wrapper for the button... include the HTML of the DOM for the form(?) when you perform the click.

Comment: I don't believe it's the selector. I tried several different ways including xpath, as well as the selector automatically generated. All behavior is the same, I see the shade of the button change like what happens when you click on it, but the click operation does not happen.

Comment: Please provide the HTML and i'll take a look, most likely you're trying to click the 'wrong' element.